# Como iterar una lista para que no me tome de nuevo los elementos que ya se han recorrido en JAVA

Tags: java, lista, java-8, sintaxis, colecciones

**Hola buenas noches compañeros**

No se si me puedan ayudar

A modo de ejercicio propio para mejorar mi lógica en programación estoy teniendo problemas con un ejercicio en Java donde dependiendo de una lista que tiene un conjunto de sub listas con letras del abecedario, donde algunas letras se repiten, por ejemplo: `[ ["Z", "J"], ["T", "H"], ["A", "Q"], ["C", "P"], ["N", "A"], ["E", "T"], ["R", "E"], ["T", "F"], ["I", "D"], ["L", "S"], ["K", "U"], ["V", "Q"]];`

necesito determinar si una palabra de tipo "String" pasada en los parámetros de una función se puede escribir con la colección de letras dada en la lista. El problema que tengo y lo que me tiene casi más de un día investigando es que las letras que contenga cada palabra pasada en los parámetros de la función no se pueden volver a usar, o sea si pasas a la función la palabra `ARBOL` no se pueden volver a usar las letras `A-R-B-O-L` al menos que se repita más de una vez las letras que conforman esa palabra.

Por el momento solo he conseguido aplanar la lista de las letras para que queden en una lista de un solo nivel quedando de esta forma:

```
[Z, J, T, H, A, Q, C, P, N, A, E, T, R, E, T, F, I, D, L, S, K, U, V, Q]
```

Este es el código que llevo con la lista aplanada haciendo uso de programación funcional

```
public boolean getPalabra(String nombre) {
        
        List<List<String>> programmers = Arrays.asList(
                   Arrays.asList("Z", "J"),
                   Arrays.asList("T", "H"),
                   Arrays.asList("A", "Q"),
                   Arrays.asList("C", "P"),
                   Arrays.asList("N", "A"),
                   Arrays.asList("E", "T"),
                   Arrays.asList("R", "E"),
                   Arrays.asList("T", "F"),
                   Arrays.asList("I", "D"),
                   Arrays.asList("L", "S"),
                   Arrays.asList("K", "U"),
                   Arrays.asList("V", "Q"));
        //En la siguiente linea se aplana la lista de dos dimensiones:              
        List<String> flatList = programmers.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(flatList);
        
        //Acá se debería recorrer la lista aplanada y evaluar si ya se ha usado una letra para la palabra pasada por los parametros de la función
        for(int i= 0; i< flatList.size(); i++) {
            
        }
        
        return true;
        }
```

No se como recorrer dicha lista para imprimir las palabras pasada a la función (debo imprimirlas) y que las letras que esas palabras usen, no se puedan volver a utilizar al menos que la letra este repetida en la lista.

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar con este ejercicio se lo agradecería muchísimo, me ayudaría para comprender la logica de este problema

Comment: ¿Por que las lista de es declarada como una lista de lista (de dos en dos) si al final la aplanas? ¿Hay alguna razón especial? ¿Por qué no hacer simplemente una lista de una dimensión con todas las letras? Por otro lado, ¿que pasa si llamo `getPalabra("ARBOL")` dos veces? ¿La primera vez debería retornarme `true` y la segunda `false` si no hay letras disponibles?

Comment: Si @Jaime es que el problema que estoy solucionando está así establecido (en una lista de dos dimensiones) entonces para iterarla mejor pues me toco aplanarla con "flatMap()", contestando a tu segunda duda es correcto, si las letras ya no se encuentra en la lista entonces la palabra "ARBOL" ya no se puede volver a imprimir. Solo se imprimen las palabras cuya letras se encuentran en la lista, (si una letra se usa en una palabra toca descontarla de la lista inmediatamente)

Answer (score 0):

**1:** podrias usar un array con las posiciones de las letras usadas y en la iteracion evaluar si la letra de la flatlist en la posicion del for existe en el array de posiciones. si es asi, se salta esa posicion (osea no hacer nada), de lo contrario agregara esa posicion al array de posiciones de letras usadas y usara esa letra para formar la oracion...

**2:** eliminar del array la letra usada de esa manera cuando se itere de nuevo esa letra no existira y por lo tanto tomara otra letra en el array...

**nota:** con la primera solucion que doy tendras un array con las posiciones de las letras que usaste por lo que lo podras reutilizar para otras funciones.

Comment: Hola Intente probar tu solución creo que conseguí algo, más sin embargo hay unas cosas que no he podido validar como por ejemplo me sigue imprimiendo la palabra cuya letra se supone que ya no está en la lista. Lo otro es que llega a un punto donde al ingresar varias palabras diferentes en ves de borrar las letras que contiene esa palabra me restablece toda la lista con las letras del abecedario D:. No se si le puedas echar un ojito para que me digas en que estoy fallando porfis. Publicaré el código que he estado haciendo como una respuesta a este post para que lo puedas observar si es posible

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a las sugerencias, he hecho el siguiente codigo para conseguir que se imprima las palabras que solo tienen las letras que estan en la lista y que no imprima las que le falta aunque sea 1 sola de las letras de la lista, Quiero recordar que las letras de la lista se deben ir eliminando cada vez que una palabra nueva las ocupe. Entonces aunque estoy avanzando no he podido validar como por ejemplo me sigue imprimiendo la palabra cuya letra se supone que ya no está en la lista. Lo otro es que llega a un punto donde al ingresar varias palabras diferentes en ves de borrar las letras que contiene esa palabra me restablece toda la lista con las letras del abecedario :/..... No se si me puedan ayudar con alguna sugerencia compañeros

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente compañeros, en esta clase tengo todo el codigo, esta comentariado:

```
public class Ejercicio {
    
    List<String> muestra= new ArrayList(); 
    
    public String getPalabra(String nombre) {
        
        //Lista con las letras del avecedario en dos niveles
        List<List<String>> programmers = Arrays.asList(
                   Arrays.asList("Z", "J"),
                   Arrays.asList("T", "H"),
                   Arrays.asList("A", "Q"),
                   Arrays.asList("C", "P"),
                   Arrays.asList("N", "A"),
                   Arrays.asList("E", "T"),
                   Arrays.asList("R", "E"),
                   Arrays.asList("T", "F"),
                   Arrays.asList("I", "D"),
                   Arrays.asList("L", "S"),
                   Arrays.asList("K", "U"),
                   Arrays.asList("V", "Q"));
                        
        //Aplanando la lista con las letras para que me quedeuna lista de 1 solo nivel:
        List<String> flatList = programmers.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.muestra=flatList;//Guardo en esta variable lo que va teniendo la lista
        
        String palabra = null;


        //Entonces para cuando i sea menor al tamaño de nuestra lista inicial:
        for(int i= 0; i< flatList.size(); i++) {
            /*Si el nombre de la palabra contiene una de las letras que esta en la lista, 
            para traer la letra de una posicion de la lista se usa el flatList.get(i):*/
            if(nombre.contains(flatList.get(i))) {
    
                palabra= nombre; //Guardamos esa palabra en la variable palabra
                flatList.remove(i); //Y eliminamos la letra de la lista contenida en dicha palabra
            }
        }
        
        /*Devolvemos la palabra que fue admitida, es decir la que contiene alguna de las letras todavia 
         *disponibles en la lista:*/
        return "La admitida: "+ palabra;
        
        }
    
        
    //Metodo para imprimir la cantidad de letras que van quedando en la lista:
        public List<String> getMuestra() {
            System.out.print("Letras que quedan de la lista: ");
            return this.muestra;
        }
    }
```

Y en el metodo main simplemente imprimo los resultados con ayuda de un bucle while que utilizo para que me pregunte cada vez si quiero continuar o no ingresando una palabra nueva:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner entradaOpcion= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner entradaPalabra= new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int opcion;     
        String palabra;

        Ejercicio resultado= new Ejercicio();

        do{
        System.out.print("\nEscoge una opcion:\n"
                + "1. Continuar \n"
                + "0. Salir"+"; \n"
                +"------------------------------------- \n");

        opcion= entradaOpcion.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Escribe una palabra");  
        palabra= entradaPalabra.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println(resultado.getPalabra(palabra));
        System.out.println(resultado.getMuestra());

        }while(opcion != 0);
        
    }
```